# Are there any units of measurement (other than the ohm) that are represented by non-latin characters?

Tags: notation, units, si-units

We have the prefix μ and the unit Ω, but other than that we seem to not use any other greek letters (or any non-latin symbols for that matter) for specifying units.

All other units – meters, seconds, Newtons, moles and so on – are represented by one or multiple latin alphabet letters.

Why is this the case?

Am I missing something?

Why is the ohm the exception?

I'm mostly asking about SI, since there could be any number of more or less wacky systems of measurement, which could use various symbols, but any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: There's sheet resistance, measured in  "Ω/□".

Comment: At first I thought your comment wasn't rendering properly, but it turns out '□' is an actual symbol that's used!

Comment: Angstroms are represented by Å, a capital A with a small circle over the top.

Comment: Not sure if you want to count the degree in Celsius: °C.

Comment: This question seems more suitable for hsm.stackexchange.com. It doesn’t seem physics-related to me. Units of measurement are not specific to physics or even to science.

Comment: I suspect that in many cases, Roman characters are the default unless there is a special reason they won't work. For Ohms, an O looks too much like a 0, so $\Omega$ is better. We needed an option micron ${\rm \mu m}$, since we had already used ${\rm mm}$ for millimeter and also capital M for ${\rm Mm}$. Angstroms were named after Anders Jonas Ångström, who is Swedish and whose last name actually does have start with the Å character [which is part of the Swedish alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85). But I'm speculating, I am not an expert on the history of unit abbreviations!